# mysql, case sensitive compare through codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I wanted to write following query through codeigniter's db helper class, guide me plz

```
SELECT * FROM table where column like binary "abc";
```

I tried

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("table");
$this->db->like("column","binary abc");
$this->db->get();
```

but it produces

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%binary abc%'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not supported directly through the like() helper, but you can do this:

```
$result = $this->db
    ->where('column like binary "abc"', NULL, FALSE)
    ->get('table')
    ->result();
```

An alternative method is:

```
$result = $this->db
    ->where('LOWER(column)', strtolower($foo), FALSE)
    ->get('table')
    ->result();
```

Notice I am using method chaining, it's a little quicker and to me is neater.

Comment: It simply lower case the field value and match with the lower case user input, it also updates the actual data sensitivity, mean if user enter "abcd" it will match with abcD in the database which is wrong. Is there any other way to work with case sensitive records except changing the column collation.

Answer (score 2):

I used that and it worked

```
$this->db->from("table_name");
$this->db->where('column_name like binary', $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

$this->db->where('column like binary "abc"');
$result=$this->db->get('table');

Regards,
Pedro