# Check captcha with lower and uppercase characters in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

I use codeigniter, i want make valid data for captcha, if captcha is mixed of lower and uppercase characters, user should insert in input like it lower or uppercase or mixed they.

in following code i tried it, but it don't check lower and uppercase characters, how can fix it?

my captcha image is as: **dAwVJ**

```
//$cap = $this->input->post('captcha');
$cap = 'dAwVJ';// if i change this to dawvj return(output) is true, i don't want this

// Then see if a captcha exists:    
$sql   = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM captcha WHERE word = ? AND ip_address = ? AND captcha_time > ?";
$binds = array(
    $cap,
    $this->input->ip_address(),
    $expiration
);
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $binds);
$row   = $query->row();

if ($row->count == 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think checking for captchas in a case-sensitive way is veeeery user-unfriendly as nobody can recognize lower/uppercase differences in a randomized captcha or your captcha is very easy to read (e.g. all letters are same size) then it's useless nonetheless ;)

Comment: Have you checked the database collation doesn't end in _ci, this would mean the sql check is case-insensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql   = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM captcha WHERE BINARY word = ? AND ip_address = ? AND captcha_time > ?";
```

Answer (score 1):

try this sql:

```
$sql   = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM captcha WHERE binary word = ? AND ip_address = ? AND captcha_time > ?";
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean case sensitive string comparison in mysql? I think it would be something like this: `WHERE word like binary ?`

Since you are using codeigniter, this may be useful: [mysql, case sensitive compare through codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538114/mysql-case-sensitive-compare-through-codeigniter)