# How to make like() method in db active record in CodeIgniter case-insensitive?

Tags: php, codeigniter

e.g. If I have these variables:

```
$variable1 = "ABCDEFG";
$variable2 = "AbCDefG";
```

and stuff in db like these:

```
ABCDEFG
IJKLMNO
PQRSTUV
...
```

And if I try to use like() method like this:

```
function get_users()
{

    $q = $this->db->select('*')
                  ->from('users')
                  ->order_by('created asc')
                  ->like('username', $variable1)
                  ->get();
    return $q;

}
```

The result will be OK and find the **ABCDEFG** record from database.

However, if I pass $variable2 with Uppercase and Lowercase the result will be none:

```
function get_users()
{

    $q = $this->db->select('*')
                  ->from('users')
                  ->order_by('created asc')
                  ->like('username', $variable2)
                  ->get();
    return $q;

}
```

, which is wrong , because I need to ignore if it is lowercase or uppercase.

How to solve this?

Btw. my db collation is **utf8_general_ci**

Comment: For your application's use, I'd recommend the following: lower/uppercasing all usernames in the DB. You gain the added advantage of not confusing users with MyUser or myuser or MYUSER being the same.

Comment: Check the answer on this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538114/mysql-case-sensitive-compare-through-codeigniter

Comment: What database are you using? I'm assuming MySQL, but to make sure it may be advised to use strtolower($string) in your php query and LOWER(`fieldname`) for your SQL query.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this one:

```
function get_users()
{

    $q = $this->db->select('*')
                  ->from('users')
                  ->order_by('created asc')
                  ->like('LOWER(username)', strtolower($variable2))
                  ->get();
    return $q;

}
```